# Visual Studio Code Type Inference Linter

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, tern

Is there any way to get [Tern-Lint](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern-lint) like functionality in VSCode for type warnings without having to write Typings for all of my code? Its already detecting what the param types of arguments should be & inferring types, but no warnings are thrown when the detected types aren't obeyed in code.